# The purpose of Smart Junction Box in a car

Tags: automatic-transmission

I am doing research about the smart junction box of a car but on the Internet there is nothing that shows its functionality. I am looking to do some research about it and try to improve its functionalities (as a project)

My questions are: What is SJB? What is its purpose in a car?

Comment: @HandyHowie - If you have the information, please post it up. SE is meant to be a repository of information. It has been the general consensus here on Mechanics.SE that we should answer these types of questions, no matter how *easy* it might be to find the information elsewhere.

Answer (score 7):

**Ford Smart Junction Box**

The features listed below depend on make, model and year.

You will not be able to flash or program the module without the Ford PMI (Programmable Module Installation) Tool.  [Here are instructions.](http://iihs.net/fsm/?dir=404&viewfile=Programmable%20Module%20Installation.pdf)

**[Here's what Googling get's you.](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=ford%20smart%20junction%20box#seen)**

- Controls Power Windows
- Controls Power Door Locks
- Controls Cruise Control
- Headlights
- Indicators
- Windshield Wipers
- Key Fob Remote Unlock
- Key Fob programming and fob association with vehicle (security)
- Air Conditioning
- Temp Display
- Factory Installed Alarm (security)

Comment: A lot of cars use this approach now. Smart Junction Box, Totally Integrated Power Module, Front Control Module etc..

Comment: Also power seats, emergency flasher, all sensor reporting to the information display